# Not able to get INSERT of SP to work

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am not able to get the INSERT portion of the below procedure to work. Any help would be appreciated....

```
@currTable varchar(100),
@ID int,
@short_Text varchar(250),
@brief_Descrip varchar(250) = Null,
@needsTranslation varchar(10) = Null,
@prev_LangString varchar(250) = Null,
@lang_String varchar(250) = Null,
@original_lang_String varchar(250) = Null,
@StringID_from_Master int,
@GUID varchar(250) = Null

        AS

        BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON;    

        DECLARE @submitDate1 DATETIME;
        SET @submitDate1 = GETDATE()
        SET @prev_LangString = @original_lang_String

        DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

        SELECT @sql = N' UPDATE  ' + QUOTENAME(@currTable) + ' SET [lang_String] = ''' + REPLACE(@lang_String,'''','''''') + ''', [date_Changed] = ''' +  convert(varchar(20), @submitDate1) + ''', [prev_LangString] = ''' + @prev_LangString + ''', [needsTranslation] = ''' + @needsTranslation + ''' WHERE ID = ' + RTRIM(@ID) +  '; ';  

            EXEC sp_executesql @sql;    

            INSERT tblPendingDBUpdates    
                (      stringMasterID,
                       databaseName,
                       databaseStringID,
                       englishText,
                       foreignLangText,
                       submitDate,
                       GUID   
                )   

            SELECT      @StringID_from_Master,
                        Database_Name,
                        dbKeyID_ofStringName,
                        @short_Text,
                        @lang_String,
                        @submitDate1,
                        @GUID    
            FROM      tblDBUsage      
            WHERE tblUniquetblStringsMaster_ID = @StringID_from_Master;


            END
```

I tried this code block only and no luck it did not INSERT to tblPendingDBUpdates.... Noticed something weird about GUID as field name so changed it in table also...

```
        AS

        BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON;    

        DECLARE @submitDate1 DATETIME;
        SET @submitDate1 = GETDATE()
       -- SET @prev_LangString = @original_lang_String

        DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

        DECLARE @currTable varchar(100);
        SET @currTable = 'tblLangenUS'
        DECLARE @ID INT;
        SET @ID = 2
        DECLARE @short_Text varchar(250);
        SET @short_Text = 'testing99'
        DECLARE @StringID_from_Master INT;
        SET @StringID_from_Master = 2    

        DECLARE @lang_String varchar(250);
        SET @lang_String = 'testing9999'
        DECLARE @GUID1 varchar(250);
        SET @GUID1 = 'Null'


            INSERT tblPendingDBUpdates    
                (      stringMasterID,
                       databaseName,
                       databaseStringID,
                       englishText,
                       foreignLangText,
                       submitDate,
                       GUID1
                )  

            SELECT      @StringID_from_Master,
                        Database_Name,
                        dbKeyID_ofStringName,
                        @short_Text,
                        @lang_String,
                        @submitDate1,
                        @GUID1    
            FROM      tblDBUsage      
            WHERE tblUniquetblStringsMaster_ID = @StringID_from_Master;


            END
```

Comment: are you getting an error message?

Comment: No error at all, just does not INSERT. In Mgmt Studio says it completes. but nothing in VS. UPDATE portion works fine. SQL Express 2008

Comment: if you run the INSERT on its own does it work?

Comment: see updated code block at the top.

Comment: Do you have a row in tblDBUsage where tblUniquetblStringsMaster_ID is 2 ?

Comment: @marc11h why did you post this question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946434/insert-statement-not-working

Comment: Yes there is a row, many where tblUniqueStringsMaster_ID is = 2

Comment: have you tried running your INSERT on its own, not in the stored proc?

Comment: yes, as stated and displayed in code block above, it says that it completes but nothing is inserted. I am really stuck on this one.

Comment: Marc shouldn't it be `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM` instead what you doing `INSERT ... SELECT FROM`?

Comment: I tried INSERT INTO same failure./

Comment: 'it says that it completes but nothing is inserted' ... How do you know that your `INSERT` is at all gettign executed?

Comment: Only the message at the bottom that says 'Query executed succesfully'  Which I guess doesn't mean that the INSERT actually  executed.

Comment: Why not ... with `EXEC sp_executesql @sql;` you are actually executing a `UPDATE` query and then going for the `INSERT` ... HENCE I ASKED THE QUESTION

Comment: can you post the entire stored procedure instead of giving bits and pieces?

Comment: I have corrected code above to remove the EXEC which is the first part of the SP, that works, the INSERT is not. Sorry, for the over sight I had the UPDATE commented out originally but missed the EXEC.

Comment: You're seeing it above.  As you suggested I am working with only the INSERT.

Comment: How many rows do you expect to be inserted into tblPendingDBUpdates when @StringID_from_Master = 2 ?

Comment: there should be 6 rows returned

Comment: What is the data type for field tblUniquetblStringsMaster_ID ?

Comment: Type is INT,   Could this problem be a permissions issue in MgmtStudio, as I have been able to get parts of the procedure to work from with VS, but not from in MgmtStudio.

Comment: No, not a permission issue. Are you sure you use the same server and the same db? Does the select alone return 6 rows?

Comment: this is all on one PC. I check the select statment alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what you need but here is a stored proc with your declarations

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc
    AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @submitDate1 DATETIME
        SET @submitDate1 = GETDATE()
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @StringID_from_Master INT
        SET @StringID_from_Master = 2  
    DECLARE @short_Text varchar(250)
        SET @short_Text = 'testing99' 
    DECLARE @lang_String varchar(250)
        SET @lang_String = 'testing9999'
       DECLARE @GUID1 varchar(250)
        SET @GUID1 = 'Null'

    BEGIN 
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    END

    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO tblPendingDBUpdates 
        (
            stringMasterID,
            databaseName,
            databaseStringID,
            englishText,
            foreignLangText,
            submitDate,
            GUID1
        )
        SELECT  
            @StringID_from_Master,
            Database_Name,
            dbKeyID_ofStringName,
            @short_Text, 
            @lang_String, 
            @submitDate1,
            @GUID1
        FROM tblDBUsage
        WHERE tblUniquetblStringsMaster_ID = @StringID_from_Master
    END
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as far I understand it ... change the SP code to below and try again ... most probably will work fine

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <SOME NAME>
AS
BEGIN

 <ALL YOUR DECLARATION HERE>

BEGIN

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END

GO

BEGIN

INSERT INTO tblPendingDBUpdates 
(stringMasterID,
databaseName,
databaseStringID,
englishText,
foreignLangText,
submitDate,
GUID1)
SELECT  @StringID_from_Master,
Database_Name,
dbKeyID_ofStringName,
@short_Text, 
@lang_String, 
@submitDate1,
@GUID1
FROM tblDBUsage
WHERE tblUniquetblStringsMaster_ID = @StringID_from_Master; 
END  
END
GO
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_TestProc, Line 53
Incorrect syntax near ';'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

Answer (score 0):

If your not getting an error message and inserting zero rows, than you select statement must not be returning anything.

what does this return?

```
select *
FROM      tblDBUsage      
WHERE tblUniquetblStringsMaster_ID = @StringID_from_Master
```

If you're first stored proc it didn't look like `@StringID_from_Master` ever got set.  That could be your problem.